# How do I make a transparent arrow inside a solid white circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-xd

I have the attached arrow/circle icon. Currently the arrow is white and the circles background is transparent. I instead want to make the circle solid white with the arrow being transparent.

I have no idea how to do this though or where to start.

Any help appreciated. I've also added the SVG code.

[image]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <g id="Group_1216" data-name="Group 1216" transform="translate(-924 -890.666)">
    <g id="Ellipse_107" data-name="Ellipse 107" transform="translate(924 890.666)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" stroke="none"/>
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" fill="none"/>
    </g>
    <line id="Line_334" data-name="Line 334" y1="24.833" transform="translate(949.178 904.451)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path id="Path_1141" data-name="Path 1141" d="M5385.5-1988.5l12.4,12.4,12.4-12.4" transform="translate(-4448.739 2905.368)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a new blank document, do *View > Show transparency grid*
2. *File > Place* the SVG file, and zoom in so you can see it (it's quite small)
3. Select all, and ungroup <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> everything repeatedly until there are no groups left
4. Select and set the arrow strokes to black (so you can see them)
5. Set the inner circle fill to white, no stroke. Delete the outer circle.
6. Select arrow paths, do *Object > Expand*
7. Select all
8. Open the PathFinder and hit the *Minus Front* button

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked